# Дружественные числа на диапазоне

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая находит все пары дружественных чисел в заданном диапазоне. Используйте функцию, которая вычисляет сумму делителей числа и функцию, которая определяет дружественные ли два числа или нет. У Вас в программе должно быть ДВЕ функции

Входные данные: Входная строка содержит два натуральных числа – границы диапазона a и b . Гарантируется, что a ≤ b .

Выходные данные: Программа должна вывести в одной строке через пробел все пары дружественных чисел в заданном диапазоне. Каждая пара должна быть взята в круглые скобки, пары разделены пробелами. Лишних пробелов в начале и в конце строки быть не должно.

Если в заданном диапазоне нет дружественных чисел, программа должна вывести 0
Мой код:

```
from math import sqrt
from itertools import groupby

pairs = {}
m = []

def divisors_sum(number):
    lst = []
    for x in range(1, int(sqrt(number))+1):
        if number%x == 0:
            if (number or x) != number//x:
                lst.append(x)
                lst.append(number//x)
            else:
                lst.append(1)
    return sum(lst)
a, b = map(int,input().split())
for i in range(a, b+1):
    aggr = divisors_sum(i)
    if i == divisors_sum(aggr) and i != aggr :
        if i not in pairs:
            pairs[i] = aggr
            m.append(i)
            m.append(aggr)
m = sorted(set(m))
if not m:
    print("0")
else:
    for i in range (0, len(m),2):
        s = str((m[i], m[i+1]))
        print(s[0:s.index(' ')] + s[s.index(' ')+1:len(s)], sep = '', end = ' ')
```

Проходит только 47% тестов. В чем проблема вроде все пары чисел сходятся?

Comment: вам нравятся программы, которые запускаешь и непонятно, что от тебя требуется. Вот и другим людям тоже не нравятся.

Comment: По делу: пары  (63020,66928) и (66992,67095) и идущие после них не являются дружественными.

Answer (score 2):

Числа правильные, но выводятся неправильными парами. Проблема в этих строчках:

```
       if i not in pairs:
            pairs[i] = aggr
            m.append(i)
            m.append(aggr)
m = sorted(set(m))
```

Вы складываете все найденные числа в один список, а потом сортируете его вне зависимости от того, какое число с каким в паре. В итоге числа принадлежащие одной паре (например, 69615 и 87633) оказываются в разных парах (потому что между этими двумя попадают еще 71145, 76084 и 79750. Нужно добавлять числа в список парами (списками, словарями или еще как - решать вам).

Answer (score 0):

Я извратился, разложил каждое число диапазона по простым множителям (со степенями), после этого можно подсчитать количество всех возможных делителей числа и маски для их нахождения. Посчитал сумму всех делителей для каждого числа и засунул в массив.
Это самая вычислительно трудоемкая часть, дальше проще.

```
for n in range(start, k+1):
second = sum_div[n-1]
if (second >= start) and (second <= k) and (second != n):
    if (n == sum_div[second-1]):
        print(n, second)
        sum_div[n-1] = 1
```

В качестве бонуса - можно искать числа не с самого начала (они уже известны), а в нужном диапазоне. эффективная факторизация на простые множители и дальнейшее нахождение масок и всех комбинаций - благодатная опция для оптимизаций. В общем от 0 до 100000 мой дубовый код без всяких numpy на тормозных родных массивах (списках) работает менее секунды. На плюсах бы все вообще летало ...